# EmberJS - Call a function whenever route changed

Tags: ember.js

I have route map like below.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('category', function() {
        this.resource('field', { path: ':field_id' });
    });
});
```

Whenever a field route changed, i need to call a function in FieldController. Is there a way to do this?

`init` function in Controller get called only once.

Comment: Do you want to trigger a method when the field route is transitioned?

Comment: yes. inside Fieldcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to do what you want and they both use the setupController hook of the [Route class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController).

First method is to do wathever you want to do in the setupController function, like so:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
 alert('myAlert');
}
```

Second method is to call the controller's method from the setupController hook of your route. I did a fiddle to show how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/237/

Both method will fire the function when the URL changes. If you want to do fire a function while staying in the same URL, then it's completely different.

Let me know if the fiddle answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Like @knikolov have said you can use the `afterModel` to be notified when is transitioned to the `FieldRoute`. To get a `FieldController` instance you can use the `this.controllerFor('field')`:

```
App.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function() {
        this.controllerFor('field').myMethod();
    }
});

App.FieldController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
    myMethod: function() {
        alert('myMethod');
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle with this sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Q5XWg/

Comment: @MarcioJunior how would i go about executing a function after the page has rendered without creating a Controller? The afterModel() function executes the second the user has been redirected.